# How to disable all logins except Network login in WordPress Multi site?

Tags: php, multisite, htaccess

I have **N** number of sites in WordPress multi-site. I want to restrict individual site login i.e.,

- `http://www.example.com/site1/wp-admin`
- `http://www.example.com/site2/wp-admin`

Only Network admin can access website/add content. i.e. only Network admin URL should be accessible: `http://www.example.com/wp-admin`. If possible all other login URLs should redirect to respective home pages. Is there any functions or `.htaccess` rule to achieve this?

`.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following at the very top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root (*before* the WordPress front-controller, ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` block):

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)wp-admin /$1 [R,L]
```

This will redirect `/<site>/wp-admin` to `/<site>/` - where the site name can consist of any of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` and `-`.

`http://www.example.com/wp-admin` is accessible as normal.

> Yes its working, if wordpress is in sub directory its not working.

If the WordPress `.htaccess` file  is in a subdirectory then you will need to modify the directive like so:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-admin /subdirectory/ [R,L]
```

However, your setup is still unclear. Do you have multiple `.htaccess` files for different WordPress installs? A single multi-site `.htaccess` in a subdirectory and no other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: No effect in website. I placed this below the rules generated by default by WordPress when changed to multi-site

Comment: As I stated above, this must go "at the top of your `.htaccess` file". In other words _before_ "the rules generated by default by WordPress".

Comment: Yes its working, if wordpress is in sub directory its not working. pls guide me
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)wp-admin /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Are you saying the WordPress multi-site `.htaccess` file (front controller) is itself in a subdirectory and all subsites are in an additional sub-subdirectory?

Comment: No. Only multi-site site itself in sub directory

Comment: Rather than pasting code in comments, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/319486/edit) to add the relevant code. It will be *much* easier to read that way.

Comment: I've updated my answer. However, it's still not clear to me of your file structure. Please update your question showing your file structure and where these sites and `.htaccess` file(s) are located. Do you have multiple `.htaccess` files? Are you updating multiple `.htaccess` files? Or a single `.htaccess` file in the root? Or subdirectory?